# How to auto-format VS Code? Copying html and pasting JSX?

Tags: javascript, jsx, visual-studio-code

Prettier is installed to help format my code, but I want to format what I've pasted.
Whenever I copy and paste from bootstrap, I have to manually change class to className, close input tags and change for to HtmlFor. How can I do this?

What I copy and paste:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

What I copy and **want** to paste

```
<div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password"/>
</div>
```

Comment: _"Is there an extension..."_ - Asking for recommendations is off-topic -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: As an aside, unless you're writing XHTML, you don't need to close `<input>` tags as they're void/self-closing elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this extension :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=riazxrazor.html-to-jsx

I guess you can add shortcut that paste and execute this extension

Comment: SOLVED, thank you, you've saved me so many hours.

Comment: In which case, @telegrace, please accept this answer by clicking on the '' character besides the answer which will mark your question as solved (as opposed to adding the word 'solved' in the title, which I'm editing out as it adds nothing to the title and accepting the answer properly denotes that the question is 'solved').

Comment: Saying thank you and not accepting the answer is like going to restaurant, appreciate the service and food, but not tipping the waiter :(